# Can't set ISO-8859-1 as charset of web-api response

Tags: asp.net, encoding, iso-8859-1

I need to set charset ISO-8859-1 for the responses of my web api controllers, and not UTF-8.

The controller for testing returns a POCO object like this:

```
public class StudyCaseController : ApiController
{
    ...
    // GET: api/StudyCase/5
    public Study Get(int id)
    {  
        ...
    }
 }
```

I've tried to set `<globalization requestEncoding="iso-8859-1" responseEncoding="iso-8859-1"/>` in the Web.config, but testing with a fiddler request like this:

```
GET http://localhost:45988/api/StudyCase/1 HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: localhost:45988
Accept: text/xml
```

I've got a response like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?    QzpcTUVESE9NRVxEZXNhcnJvbGxvQ1xQcm95ZWN0b3NcVmlld0NhcE1hblxWaWV3Q2FwTWFuXGFwaVxT    dHVkeUNhc2VcMQ==?=
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Tue, 24 Mar 2015 11:36:13 GMT
Content-Length: 1072

<?xml version="1.0"?>
... etc...
```

I've also tried to specify the charset at the request with `Accept-Charset: iso-8859-1` but the same result.

For more info, i've tested it with IIS Express and IIS Server.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can set supported encodings for formatters in `HttpConfiguration` class. 28591 is codepage for ISO-8859-1 (Latin 1).

```
config.Formatters.Add(new XmlMediaTypeFormatter());
config.Formatters[0].SupportedEncodings.Clear();
config.Formatters[0].SupportedEncodings.Add(Encoding.GetEncoding(28591));
```

Answer (score 0):

Dealing with the problem my self, I found out that the problem was indeed the XML MediaTypeFormatter.

It does not support ISO-8859-1 and without the ability to change the server-side code I was forced to use another MediaTypeFormatter

https://www.nuget.org/packages/NetBike.Xml.Formatting/

or in nuget console

```
Install-Package NetBike.Xml.Formatting
```

This solved my problem (in a project using Web API 2).
Here is a demonstration of one way to set this using the HttpClient

```
private static HttpClient httpClient;
private static MediaTypeFormatter formatter;
private static List<MediaTypeFormatter> formatters;

public static void loadSettings()
{
    //httpClient settings are set here

    formatters = new List<MediaTypeFormatter>();
    formatter = new NetBike.Xml.Formatting.NetBikeXmlMediaTypeFormatter();
    formatters.Add(formatter);
}

public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetContent(string requestMethod)
{
    try
    {
        var returnValue = await httpClient.GetAsync(requestMethod);
        return returnValue;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Communicator.GetXml: " + ex.Message);
    }

    return null;
}

public static async void testStuff()
{
    var httpResponse = await GetContent("http://someDomain.com/someMethod");
    MyModelObject myModel = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsAsync<MyModelObject>(formatters);
}
```

<strike>What you want to do, is to set this as a default formatter for the whole project.</strike>

-EDIT-

Microsoft argues that this behavior is intended.
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/958121

I have experienced issues with the NetBike Formatter, when formatting advanced XML objects, and even have a case where it writes BOM to the output.

Therefore I do not recommend it above the default MediaTypeSerializer, instead the solution falls back to the old "it depends"

That looks like this in code

```
        List<MediaTypeFormatter> formatters = new List<MediaTypeFormatter>();
        MediaTypeFormatter badencodingFormatter = new NetBike.Xml.Formatting.NetBikeXmlMediaTypeFormatter();
        badencodingFormatter.SupportedEncodings.Clear();
        badencodingFormatter.SupportedEncodings.Add(Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1"));
        MediaTypeFormatter defaultFormatter = new CustomXmlMediaTypeFormatter();
        formatters.Add(badencodingFormatter);
        formatters.Add(defaultFormatter);
```

This makes sure that anoying encoding is handled by NetBike, but only in those (hopefully rare) cases